# How to define precision as loss Function in Keras?

Tags: keras, loss-function

It’s known that sparse_categorical_crossentropy in keras can get the average loss function among each category.  But what if only one certain category was I concerned most?  Like if I want to define the precision(=TP/(TP+FP)) based on this category as loss function, how can I write it? Thanks！

My codes were like:

```
from keras import backend as K
def my_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    y_true = K.cast(y_true,"float32")
    y_pred = K.cast(K.argmax(y_pred),"float32")
    nominator = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(y_true,y_pred) & K.equal(y_true, 0),"float32"))
    denominator = K.sum(K.cast(K.equal(y_pred,0),"float32"))
    return -(nominator + K.epsilon()) / (denominator + K.epsilon())
```

And the error is like:

```
argmax is not differentiable
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend you to use precision as the loss function.

- It is not differentiable that can't be set as a loss function for nn.
- you can max it by predicting all the instance as class negative, that makes no sense.

One of the alternative solution is using F1 as the loss function, then tuning the probability cut-off manually for obtaining a desirable level of precision as well as recall is not too low.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the fit method a parameter `class_weight` where you determine which classes are more important.

It should be a dictionary:

```
{
    0: 1, #class 0 has weight 1
    1: 0.5, #class 1 has half the importance of class 0
    2: 0.7, #....
    ...
}
```

**Custom loss**

If that is not exactly what you need, you can create loss functions like:

```
import keras.backend as K

def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):

    create operations with yTrue and yPred
        - yTrue = the true output data (equal to y_train in most examples)        
        - yPred = the model's calculated output

        - yTrue and yPred have exactly the same shape: (batch_size,output_dimensions,....) 
             - according to the output shape of the last layer
             - also according to the shape of y_train    

    all operations must be like +, -, *, / or operations from K (backend)

    return someResultingTensor
```

Comment: Thank you but the answer may not be the one that I'm looking for. Maybe is the wrong description mislead you. So I re-edited the question. Could you give me a new answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot used argmax as it is not differentiable. That means that backprop will not work if loss function can't be differentiated.

Instead of using argmax, do y_true * y_pred.